# Pygame, joystick detecting doesn't work

Tags: python, pygame, joystick

I'm trying to detect an USB Joystick with Pygame.
Every time when I run this code the program crashes with the error:
"Joystick not initialized" in line 10.

```
import pygame as p

p.init()
stick = p.joystick.Joystick(0)
#get init returns always False
print("initialized:",bool(stick.get_init()))
#getting the name works as it should
print(stick.get_name())
#says always "pygame.error: Joystick not initialized"
print("axis_0",stick.get_axis(0))   
p.quit()
```

Do I do something wrong or is this a bug? (I am using the newest pygame version on Python 3.2 and Windows 7.)
Thanks for every information

Answer (score 4):

I just started with Pygame myself. I used `pygame.joystick.init()` first. So, I guess you would replace `p.init()` with `p.joystick.init()`.

From the Pygame documentation: (http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/joystick.html)

> You can call the Joystick.get_name - get the Joystick system name and
>   Joystick.get_id - get the Joystick ID functions without initializing
>   the Joystick object.

I think you also have to put a line in there that says:

```
stick.init()
```

to then initialize the stick and receive events from it.